# Can't find com.dropbox.client2 package

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, package, dropbox

I'm trying to make a simple application in Eclipse, using java, that could upload a file from my computer to Dropbox but when I try to do that, I'm having the problem that Eclipse can't find the package com.dropbox.client2 even though I downloaded the Dropbox Java SDK packages and imported them.

I need some help, thank you in advance.

Later edit: I figured it out. First time I downloaded dropbox-java-sdk-1.7.6.jar, and the problem was still there, but then I downloaded dropbox-client-1.5.3.jar and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you told eclipse to use the jar?

From your Eclipse workspace, right click your project on the left pane -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Add Jars -> add your jars here.

Comment: Yes, I did this but the problem is still there.

Comment: I haven't used Eclipse in a long time, but I know with IntelliJ, it sometimes just needs a restart/remove library and re-add it